# Error al abrir el fichero. Falla PdfPTable iText - JAVA

Tags: java, sql, pdf, itext

Estoy realizando una impresión en PDF gracias a la clase **iText**. Tengo la consulta realizada la cual me muestra los datos de los clientes de mi base de datos, la consulta funciona tanto en **SQL** como en comandos. Me imprime los datos en un PDF correctamente pero ahora quiero añadir esos datos en una tabla donde veremos los nombres, apellidos, dni, tlf, direccion, ciudad, email de cada cliente.

Realizo el siguiente código para insertar la tabla pero al abrir el documento PDF (me lo genera correctamente el NetBeans) me dice: "Error al abrir el documento."

Código:
public class PDF_Clientes_Tabla {
    //Ruta del archivo dentro del proyecto de Netbeans.
    public static String archivo = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/listado_clientes_tabla.pdf";

```
public static void crearPDF(ArrayList<Cliente> clientes) throws DocumentException{
    //Declaramos un documento como un objecto Document. 
    Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 80, 80, 75, 75);
    //writer es declarado como el método utilizado para escribir en el archivo.
    PdfWriter writer = null;

    try{
        //Obtenemos la instancia del archivo a utilizar.
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(archivo));
    }catch(FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    //Agregamos un título al documento.
    documento.addTitle("ARCHIVO PDF GENERADO DESDE JAVA");

    //Abrimos el documento a editar.
    documento.open();

    try{
        //Obtenemos la instancia de la imagen/logo.
        Image imagen = Image.getInstance("..\\imagenes\\LOGO.png");
        //Alineamos la imagen al centro del documento.
        imagen.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //Agregamos la imagen al documento.
        documento.add(imagen);
    }catch(IOException | DocumentException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    //Creamos un párrafo nuevo llamado "vacio1" para espaciar los elementos.
    Paragraph vacio1 = new Paragraph();
    vacio1.add("\n\n");
    documento.add(vacio1);

    //Declaramos un texto llamado "titulo" como Paragraph. 
    //Le podemos dar formato alineado, tamaño, color, etc.
    Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph();
    titulo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
    titulo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Times New Roman", 24, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.RED));
    titulo.add("***LISTADO DE CLIENTES***");

    try{
        //Agregamos el texto "titulo" al documento.
        documento.add(titulo);
    }catch(DocumentException ex){
        ex.getMessage();
    }

    //Creamos un párrafo nuevo llamado "saltolinea1" simulando un salto de linea para espaciar
    //los elementos del PDF.
    Paragraph saltolinea1 = new Paragraph();
    saltolinea1.add("\n\n");
    documento.add(saltolinea1);

    //Variable con el numero de clientes que hay en la tabla clientes.
    int numero_clientes = ConexionesPDFTabla.numero_clientes();
    //Añadimos una tabla de 7 columnas.
    PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(7);
    //Añadimos los títulos a la tabla.
    tabla.addCell("NOMBRE"); 
    tabla.addCell("APELLIDOS"); 
    tabla.addCell("DNI"); 
    tabla.addCell("TLF_CONTACTO"); 
    tabla.addCell("DIRECCION"); 
    tabla.addCell("CIUDAD"); 
    tabla.addCell("EMAIL"); 

    //Recorremos cada arrayList e imprimimos los resultados. 
    for (int i = 0; i < numero_clientes; i++){ 
    tabla.addCell("NOMBRE"); 
    tabla.addCell("APELLIDOS"); 
    tabla.addCell("DNI"); 
    tabla.addCell("TLF_CONTACTO"); 
    tabla.addCell("DIRECCION"); 
    tabla.addCell("CIUDAD"); 
    tabla.addCell("EMAIL"); 
    }

    //Añadimos la tabla "tabla" al documento "documento".
    documento.add(tabla);   
    //Cerramos el documento.
    documento.close();
    //Cerramos el writer.
    writer.close();
}
```

}

Los datos son "enfarragosos" pero es para probar una tabla sencilla pero ni aún así me funciona al abrir el fichero.

Comment: Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas añadiendo a una tabla de 7 columnas, el toString de cliente entero, deberias hacerlo algo así:

```
int numero_clientes = ConexionesPDFTabla.numero_clientes();
PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(7);
// Aqui puedes añadir una fila con los titulos
//tabla.addCell("Nombre");
//tabla.addCell("DNI");
//Y asi los 7 campos
for (int i = 0; i < numero_clientes; i++){

    tabla.addCell(clientes.get(i).getNombre());
    tabla.addCell(clientes.get(i).getApellidos());
    //Y asi los 7 campos
}
documento.add(tabla);
```

Si quieres los titulos en negrita, te pongo uno de ejemplo.

```
Paragraph cabecera=new Paragraph("Nombre");
cabecera.getFont().setStyle(Font.BOLD);
Cell cell=new Cell(cabecera);
table.addCell(cell);
```

EDIT tal y como recibes los clientes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numero_clientes; i++){
        String[] cliente=clientes.get(i).split(" ");
        tabla.addCell(cliente[0]);
        tabla.addCell(cliente[1]);
        //Y asi los 7 campos
    }
```

Comment: me da error en "clientes.get(i).getNombre()"

Comment: Como es tu clase cliente?

Comment: No tengo clase cliente... ahí esta el problema. ¿Debo crearla o no vale con los campos cogidos en la consulta SQL?

Comment: Cuál es el retorno de clientes.get(i)?

Comment: Me retorna todo el arrayList...

Comment: Actualizo la pregunta y le dejo la función para que veas el retorno de clientes.get(i).

Comment: Pero que contienen esos strings? El id del cliente o todos los datos?

Comment: Todos los datos, como ves hago un String cliente de todos los atributos del cliente, y lo añado al arrayList clientes: clientes.add(cliente);

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50773/discussion-between-reyjuanjo-and-omaza1990).